# Substitute variable?

Tags: maxima

I'm trying to substitute `L` with `Lα`:

```
f(x) := c * (x + L);
c: L;
f(x), L: Lα;
```

I expected the output:

```
Lα * (x + Lα)
```

instead I got

```
L * (x + Lα)
```

Maybe I should `define` `f(x)` instead?

```
kill(all);

define(
  f(x),
  c * (x + L)
);

c: L;
f(x), L: Lα;
```

Nope — same result.

Do I substitute `L` for `Lα` in a wrong way?

**Edit**:

Turns out it is expected behaviour, as maxima `ev`avluates expression only once. One [can impose "infinite evaluation"](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/maxima-discuss/thread/slrno3ag4g.4qn.robert.dodier%40freekbox.fglan/#msg35508602) via the flag infeval:

```
f(x), L: La, infeval;
 => La*(x + La)
```

Another solution is to use [subst](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#subst) instead:

```
subst(
  Lα, L, f(x)
  );
```

([source](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/maxima-discuss/thread/CACLVabV3dHAM8GsHA9pEPwR5dFdHgudC2QBew_82wJeY_YdoqQ%40mail.gmail.com/#msg35508035))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra `eval` step to make this work:

```maxima
f(x) := c * (x + L);
c: L;
f(x), L: Lα, eval;
```

Output:

```
Lα (x + Lα)
```

Comment: Great, it works. Can you comment on why maxima works this way? Is it related to the order in which expression is evaluated?

Comment: @Adobe: AFAIK only one evaluation is done by default ([altough there are exceptions](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_8.html#evflag)), that means `c=L`, in order to go to `c=L=La` maxima requires a second evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Use subst instead of ev.

```
(%i1) f(x) := c * (x + L)$
(%i2) c: L$
(%i3) subst(L=La,f(x));
(%o3) La (x + La)
```

But keep in mind that the function continues to be c*(x+L). The symbol c has been bound to L and if you then bind the symbol L to La, c will continue to be bound to L and not to La. Maxima variables work as in Lisp, which might be different to what you are used to in other languages.